# Google Chrome file system api: bug in sample code?

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, google-chrome-app

I am trying to run this example code:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/filesystem-access

as well as this:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/storage

I am not able to get either of them to run in my browser: Chrome 26.0.1410.65 Mac Lion 10.7.5

(to see it run, download it and click on html page included with each of the examples)

If you can confirm this is a bug in the sample code (it doesn't run in your system as well) please let me know where I should file this bug report. (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/ or https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/issues?)

many thanks in advance.

Comment: @BeardFist, nothing happens when I click the button. No action. Here is the error message on console: http://puu.sh/2Kmkv.png

Comment: good point, let me try that.

Comment: When I load it as extension, it works. Feeling a bit stupid :), could you add it as an answer so I can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `Load unpacked extension` button found on the `chrome://extensions` page and then launch the app in order for it to use `chrome.*` API's.